# Bootstrap css not working on dynamically injected components in angular

Tags: css, angular, bootstrap-4

I have a code block like:

```
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="row">
      <ng-template dynamicComponents></ng-template>
    </div>
  </div>
```

`dynamicComponents` is a directive using which I inject dynamic components.

All the application is using Bootstrap and is working fine but the dynamically injected components are shrinking or not working with bootstrap css, I even tried using `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` but it doesn't seem to work.

Please refer the screenshots below:

[image]

Here everything works fine till class=row and it is taing the full width, but once a dynamic component named `app-from-builder-components-editor` is injected it breaks up the bootstrap properties, please see below:

[image]

What can I do to get the bootstrap properties to work ?

Comment: How is bootstrap integarted in you app? css in index,html or scss iincluded in styles.scss?

Comment: @Marc it is used from css in angular.json

Comment: A workaround is to use angular material and angular flex layout:   https://tburleson-layouts-demos.firebaseapp.com/#/docs.

Comment: remove it from the angular.json file and write this in your styles.css 

@import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'

Comment: @Flightdoc5242 does not work that way either, I have already tried placing the file at separate locations / methods

Comment: I am favoring @S Ps answer, Can you add an example of a component's HTML which you inject via `dynamicComponents`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your component host (app-form-builder-components-editor) that sits between your row and col divs. To make it work, your 'col-md-12' div should be a direct child of your 'row' div.

What you could do is putting the `<div class="row">` inside your app-form-builder component's template to work around this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by using containers:

```
<ng-template>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <!-- content --> 
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <!-- content --> 
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

Not ideal, but it seems to stop the layout issue. Angular templates seem to rewrite the DOM and nest the rows, for some reason. This "resolves" the issue.